# Express logarithm in terms

Tags: logarithms

> Given that $\log_m{x^2y} = n$  and $\log_m{\frac x{y^2}} = p$, express
>   $\log_m{\frac x{y}}$ in terms of $n$ and $p$

Help me to solve this question. Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not a free service for your homework question. Tell us what you tried, where did you find difficulties, what is unclear, etc. Also, please use mathjax to typeset mathematics instead of posting a picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we have,

$$
\begin{cases} 
2\log_m x+ \log_m y = n\\ 
\log_m x- 2\log_m y = p
\end{cases},
$$

Then we can simplify as:
$$
\begin{cases} 
2A+ B = n\\ 
A- 2B = p
\end{cases},
$$

where $A=\log_m x$ and $B=\log_m y$. 
By simplification we have: 
$B= \frac{-2p+n}{5}$ and $A= \frac{n - \frac{-2p+n}{5}}{2} = \frac{2n+p}{5}.$

Now, $\log_m{\frac{x}{y}} = A-B = \frac{n+3p}{5}$!!!